# Flatten nested json in Scala Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, multidimensional-array, apache-spark-sql

I have  multiple jsons coming from any restapi's and I don't know the schema of it. I am unable to use the explode function of dataframes , because i am unaware about the column names, which is getting created by spark api.

1.Can we store the keys of the nested arrays elements keys by decoding values from `dataframe.schema.fields`, As spark only provides the value part in the rows of the dataframe and take the top level key as column name.

Dataframe --

```
+--------------------+
|       stackoverflow|
+--------------------+
|[[[Martin Odersky...|
+--------------------+
```

Is there any optimal way to flatten the json by using the dataframe methods via determining the schema at the run time.

Sample Json -:

```
{
  "stackoverflow": [{
    "tag": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "scala",
      "author": "Martin Odersky",
      "frameworks": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Play Framework"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Akka Framework"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
    {
      "tag": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "java",
        "author": "James Gosling",
        "frameworks": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Apache Tomcat"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Spring Boot"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note - We need to do all the operations in dataframe , because there is a huge amount of data , that is coming and we cannot parse each and every json.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Try to avoid flattening all columns as much as possible.**

Created helper function & You can directly call `df.explodeColumns` on DataFrame.

Below code will flatten multi level array & struct type columns.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.util.Try

implicit class DFHelpers(df: DataFrame) {
    def columns = {
      val dfColumns = df.columns.map(_.toLowerCase)
      df.schema.fields.flatMap { data =>
        data match {
          case column if column.dataType.isInstanceOf[StructType] => {
            column.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType].fields.map { field =>
              val columnName = column.name
              val fieldName = field.name
              col(s"${columnName}.${fieldName}").as(s"${columnName}_${fieldName}")
            }.toList
          }
          case column => List(col(s"${column.name}"))
        }
      }
    }

    def flatten: DataFrame = {
      val empty = df.schema.filter(_.dataType.isInstanceOf[StructType]).isEmpty
      empty match {
        case false =>
          df.select(columns: _*).flatten
        case _ => df
      }
    }
    def explodeColumns = {
      @tailrec
      def columns(cdf: DataFrame):DataFrame = cdf.schema.fields.filter(_.dataType.typeName == "array") match {
        case c if !c.isEmpty => columns(c.foldLeft(cdf)((dfa,field) => {
          dfa.withColumn(field.name,explode_outer(col(s"${field.name}"))).flatten
        }))
        case _ => cdf
      }
      columns(df.flatten)
    }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.util.Try
defined class DFHelpers
```

**Flattened Columns**

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- stackoverflow: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- tag: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- author: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- frameworks: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)


scala> df.explodeColumns.printSchema
root
 |-- author: string (nullable = true)
 |-- frameworks_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- frameworks_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)

scala>
```

Comment: are you facing any issue ?

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment .

if i append this extra piece in the bottom of given array above  
`"npi": {
"$numberInt": "2038094571"
},
"part_names": "VALARIE",
"salary": {
"$numberInt": "250000"
}
}`
It is finding duplicate columns "$numberInt" while flatteining and throwing exception

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference '$numberInt' is ambiguous, could be: $numberInt, $numberInt.;

It is not able to find subdocument duplicate keys in colums_* method.

Comment: let me check this.

Comment: I have updated code & try again now & let me know if its not working .. ??

Comment: Great , It works now .
I guess now we are not comparing column values with the subdocument values , instead we are just appending "_" after the column name.
is it possible that we can create a map at run time and keep adding the new values we get  and compare values with the subdocument values . It will look more messy than i guess.
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: This approach i have not tried. Recently I have encounter duplicate issue & I have updated solution by adding "_". now no more duplicates.. one more issue I can see is if you have same columns in json like empName & empname it will fail again with duplicate issue. to fix that use this - spark.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=true")

Comment: @Srinivas- I'm trying to accomplish the same kind of scenario with spark structured streaming. Reading jsonstring from kafka with dynamic schema(each record can have different schema;one record can have 5 columns, other record may have 3 columns). It's a nested one, im flattening that and loading that to hbase using foreachwriter. But my real problem is schema inference, without schema. Spark doesn't support it. Any leads will be greatly helpful.Thanks

Comment: You can use above logic inside of ```foreachBatch``` .. I have not tried this.try it once.

Comment: But i want to parse and flatten it on row level. Above operation is on dataframe level.Each record in dataframe will have different schema.Please correct me..if my statement is wrong.Thanks again.

Comment: How are you storing different schemas in dataframe ?? :)

Comment: From Kafka, single column called value, which contains jsonstring will be read through streaming. Schema will not be defined.It will tend to change.We need to parse & flatten that jsonstring before loading to hbase.

Comment: @Srinivas Hi, your approach is impressive. Just curious why this kind of functionality is not supported natively in Spark (i think this is a very common use case), do you have any idea?

Comment: @jack, thanks.. I am not sure on that point.

Comment: @Srinivas thanks a lot. Was looking for tail recursive approach of spark dataframe flatten. This dataframe extension works very charm.