# Unable to fetch Json Column using sparkDataframe:org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'explode;

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Can Someone Help me In this Scenario.I am reading one Json File using spark/scala and then trying to access column name but while accessing the column name i am getting below error message.

```
     org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 
    'explode(`b2b_bill_products_prod_details`.`amt`)' 
    due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be 
     array or map type, not DoubleType;;
```

Please see the Json Schema and my code below.

```
     root
     |-- b2b: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- add1: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- bill: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- amt: double (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- products: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- prod_details: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- amt: double (nullable = true)
```

I want to access amt field(last line in the json schema) I am writing below spark/scala code

```
    df.withColumn("b2b_bill",explode($"b2b.bill"))
    .withColumn("b2b_bill_products",explode($"b2b_bill.products"))
    .withColumn("b2b_bill_products_prod_details", explode($"b2b_bill_products.prod_details"))
    .withColumn("b2b_bill_products_prod_details_amt",explode($"b2b_bill_products_prod_details.amt"))
```

Comment: If you have more columns & don't want to go & explode individual columns, check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863489/flatten-nested-json-in-scala-spark-dataframe/61863579#61863579 .. It will give flatten all nested complex columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 4th `explode` function is applied on the `amt: double` column, wherein the explode function expects `array/map` input type. Thats the error reported.

### Edit

You can access the inner most `amt` field with the expression given below,

```
df.withColumn("b2b_bill",explode($"b2b.bill"))
  .withColumn("b2b_bill_products",explode($"b2b_bill.products"))
  .withColumn("b2b_bill_products_prod_details_amt", $"b2b_bill_products.element.prod_details.amt")
```

Comment: Yes that issue i understood.Please suggest me how should i modify my code so i can access that amt Column.

Comment: @RahulPatidar, I have updated the answer, check if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot,Yes I am able to fetch columns.