# Spark Dynamically Json Parsing into key value strings

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, parsing, pyspark

I am trying to convert a generic json into key value string dynamically (atleast 3 level nesting).
e.g:
Json:

```
{
    "a": {
        "d": "1",
        "e": "2",
        "f": "3",
        "g": {
            "h": [{
                "i": "4",
                "j": "5",
                "k": "6",
                "l": true,
                "m": true,
                "n": 1821,
                "o": false
            }, {
                "i": "7",
                "g": "8",
                "l": false,
                "m": false,
                "o": false
            }]
        },
        "l": false
    },
    "b": {
        "p": {
            "q": {
                "h": [{
                    "i": "7",
                    "g": "8",
                    "l": false,
                    "m": false,
                    "o": false,
                    "r": "FALSE"
                }, {
                    "i": "4",
                    "j": "5",
                    "k": "6",
                    "l": true,
                    "m": true,
                    "n": 1821,
                    "o": false,
                    "r": "FALSE"
                }]
            }
        },
        "s": [{
            "t": {
                "u": ["xxx:*"],
                "v": "333",
                "w": "10"
            }
        }],
        "x": [{
            "y": "DEFAULT"
        }]
    },
    "c": {
        "z": "100",
        "zz": "2020-11-06T07:15:25.836Z"
    }
}
```

Result : key value string something like:

```
a.d=1
a.e=2
a.f=3
a.g.h.i=4
a.g.h.j=5
a.g.h.k=6
a.g.h.l=True
a.g.h.m=True
a.g.h.n=1821
a.g.h.o=False
a.g.h.i=7
a.g.h.g=8
a.g.h.l=False
a.g.h.m=False
a.g.h.o=False
a.l=False
b.p.q.h.i=7
b.p.q.h.g=8
b.p.q.h.l=False
b.p.q.h.m=False
b.p.q.h.o=False
b.p.q.h.r=FALSE
b.p.q.h.i=4
b.p.q.h.j=5
b.p.q.h.k=6
b.p.q.h.l=True
b.p.q.h.m=True
b.p.q.h.n=1821
b.p.q.h.o=False
b.p.q.h.r=FALSE
b.s.t.u=["xxx:*"]
b.s.t.v=333
b.s.t.w=10
b.x.y=DEFAULT
c.z=100
c.zz=2020-11-06T07:15:25.836Z
```

Here keys might come anything so can't use the hardcoded string value of key to parse.
I tried loading in spark by
rdd = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("s3:///jsontest/*.json")

which gives me key as a json file name and json string as a value, now I don't know how I can parse the json string and convert that into list of string which contains key value structure.
Also, wants to process different schema json ata time like in pairRDD we have key as filename and value as jsonstring, so every jsonstring should convert into key value for that specific filename only
Let me know if any idea how can I do this

Comment: are you using python or scala ?

Comment: any language will work python,scala or java

Comment: You can check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863489/flatten-nested-json-in-scala-spark-dataframe/61863579#61863579 & change as per your requirement

Comment: this helps but it gives me all data in tabular format not in key value types ,I mean there is only two columns in my table (key,value) I think after this a transpose will help , any thoughts?

Comment: Once you got tabular format you can move those columns into map, You will get data as key, value.

Comment: okay , and what if I want to use different json at a time (*.json) which might having different schema

Comment: use ```spark.read.json``` instead of ```spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles``` & spark will read json files & merge all schema under one schema, then you can flatten all columns.

Comment: check below post if not work let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224616/discussion-between-bunty-and-srinivas).

Answer (score 1):

[Check this post for flatten columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863489/flatten-nested-json-in-scala-spark-dataframe/61863579#61863579), I am using `explodeColumns` from that post.

Read All json files using `json` function & then use `explodeColumns`.

```
val df = spark.read.json("/your/json/directory/").explodeColumns
```

To get data in key, value pair, Check below code.

```
df.select(map(df.columns.flatMap(c => Seq(lit(c),col(c))):_*).as("map")).show(false)
```

Comment: I am getting some data type mismatch error :  due to data type mismatch: The given values of function map should all be the same type, but they are [string, string, string, string, string, bigint, string, boolean, string, boolean, boolean, string, boolean, string, string, string, string, bigint, string, string, boolean, string, boolean, boolean, string];  And 1 more thing is there a way I can map the filename with the key generated .

Comment: Yes, Map should contains same datatypes..I think you have to cast all data types into string.