# pyspark automatically extract fields inside json to top level columns

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a json like below:

```
{"name":"Michael"}
{"name":"Andy", "age":30}
{"name":"Justin", "age":19}
{"name":"Bob", "age":29,"city":"New York"}
{"name":"Ross", "age":49,"data":{"id":1,"Name":"Test"}}
```

The following pyspark code:

```
sc = spark.sparkContext

peopleDF = spark.read.json("people.json")
peopleDF.createOrReplaceTempView("people")
tableDF = spark.sql("SELECT * from people")
tableDF.show()
```

Produces this output:

```
+----+--------+---------+-------+
| age|    city|     data|   name|
+----+--------+---------+-------+
|null|    null|     null|Michael|
|  30|    null|     null|   Andy|
|  19|    null|     null| Justin|
|  29|New York|     null|    Bob|
|  49|    null|{Test, 1}|   Ross|
+----+--------+---------+-------+
```

But I'm looking for an output like below (Notice how the element inside data have become columns:

```
+----+--------+----+----+-------+
| age|    city|  id|Name|   name|
+----+--------+----+----+-------+
|null|    null|null|null|Michael|
|  30|    null|null|null|   Andy|
|  19|    null|null|null| Justin|
|  29|New York|null|null|    Bob|
|  49|    null|   1|Test|   Ross|
+----+--------+----+----+-------+
```

The fields inside the data struct change constantly and so I cannot pre-define the columns. Is there a function in pyspark that can automatically extract every single element in a struct to its top level column? (Its okay if the performance is slow)

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863489/flatten-nested-json-in-scala-spark-dataframe/61863579#61863579

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"." operator` to access nested elements and flatten your schema.

```
import spark.implicits._

val js = """[{"name":"Michael"},{"name":"Andy", "age":30},{"name":"Justin", "age":19},{"name":"Bob", "age":29,"city":"New York"},{"name":"Ross", "age":49,"data":{"id":1,"Name":"Test"}}]"""
val df = spark.read.json(Seq(js).toDS).select("age", "city", "data.Name", "data.id", "name")
df.show()
+----+--------+----+----+-------+
| age|    city|Name|  id|   name|
+----+--------+----+----+-------+
|null|    null|null|null|Michael|
|  30|    null|null|null|   Andy|
|  19|    null|null|null| Justin|
|  29|New York|null|null|    Bob|
|  49|    null|Test|   1|   Ross|
+----+--------+----+----+-------+
```

If you want to flatten schema without selecting columns manually, you can use the following method to do it:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

def flattenSchema(schema: StructType, prefix: String = null) : Array[Column] = {
  schema.fields.flatMap(f => {
    val colName = if (prefix == null) f.name else (prefix + "." + f.name)

    f.dataType match {
      case st: StructType => flattenSchema(st, colName)
      case _ => Array(col(colName))
    }
  })
}

val js = """[{"name":"Michael"},{"name":"Andy", "age":30},{"name":"Justin", "age":19},{"name":"Bob", "age":29,"city":"New York"},{"name":"Ross", "age":49,"data":{"id":1,"Name":"Test"}}]"""
val df = spark.read.json(Seq(js).toDS)
df.select(flattenSchema(df.schema):_*).show()
```