# parsing complex nested json in Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am having a complex json with below schema which i need to convert to a dataframe in spark. Since the schema is compex I am unable to do it completely.

The Json file has a very complex schema and using explode with column select might be problematic

Below is the schema which I am trying to convert:

```
root
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- meta: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- view: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- approvals: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- reviewedAt: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- reviewedAutomatically: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- submissionDetails: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- permissionType: string (nullable =
```

I have used the below code to flatten the data but still there nested data which i need to flatten into columns:

```
 def flattenStructSchema(schema: StructType, prefix: String = null) : Array[Column] = {
            schema.fields.flatMap(f => {
                  val columnName = if (prefix == null)
                        f.name else (prefix + "." + f.name)

                  f.dataType match {
                        case st: StructType => flattenStructSchema(st, columnName)
                        case _ => Array(col(columnName).as(columnName.replace(".","_")))
                  }
            })
      }

     val df2 = df.select(col("meta"))

     val df4 = df.select(col("data"))


     val df3 = df2.select(flattenStructSchema(df2.schema):_*).show()
     df3.printSchema()
     df3.show(10,false)
```

Comment: Hi :) please share any relevant code you have in which you attempt to handle this json. Other will better be able to help you by seeing what you’ve already done.

Comment: Are you having problems with reading complex JSON files or you don't know how to parse dataframe with complex structure? Please explain a bit more what your problem is.

Comment: I am not sure how to parse this complex json to dataframe. I am new to spark due to which I am unable to figure out.

Comment: I know we use explode function to get the data which I have done but here its more nested and getting all the columns from the array will be difficult when I have specify them manually

Comment: tried to use the below to flatten the data but work still in progress as there are still nested data which needs to be flattened

Comment: Please check this post  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863489/flatten-nested-json-in-scala-spark-dataframe/61863579#61863579 it might help you.

Comment: Thanks Srinivas. I will give it a try