# Flattening Nested JSON with Scala with Period "." in key name

Tags: json, scala

I feel like I've met a catch 22. I'm trying to flatten REST API output with keys like "odata.id", "odata.type". The flattening code I've used before isn't working because of the "." in the key name. I can't rename columns without first flattening, but I can't seem to flatten as the fieldname calls are getting thrown off.

The JSON looks like this.

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_api/$metadata#SP.ApiData.Files12",
    "value": [
        {
            "odata.type": "SP.File",
            "odata.id": "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/relativePath.xlsx')",
            "odata.editLink": "Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/fullPath.xlsx')",
            "CheckInComment": "",
            "CheckOutType": 2,
            "ContentTag": "{tag},6,7",
            "CustomizedPageStatus": 0,
            "ETag": "\"{tag},6\"",
            "Exists": true,
            "IrmEnabled": false,
            "Length": "28999",
            "Level": 1,
            "LinkingUri": "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/filePath?d=id",
            "LinkingUrl": "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/filePath?d=id",
            "MajorVersion": 6,
            "MinorVersion": 0,
            "Name": "fileName.xlsx",
            "ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/relativePath.xlsx",
            "TimeCreated": "2022-03-23T11:30:28Z",
            "TimeLastModified": "2022-03-23T12:11:34Z",
            "Title": "",
            "UIVersion": 3072,
            "UIVersionLabel": "6.0",
            "UniqueId": "id"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using the following code that I've inherited. (I also tried with code from this [Flatten nested json in Scala Spark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863489/flatten-nested-json-in-scala-spark-dataframe), but I get the same error.)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, current_timestamp, lit, to_timestamp}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
def flattenDataframe(
                        df: DataFrame, 
                        keepParentFieldName: Boolean = false, 
                        excludeArrayFlattenCols: String = ""
                      ): DataFrame = {

    val fields = df.schema.fields
    val fieldNames = fields.map(x => x.name)
    val length = fields.length
    val dontFlattenList: List[String] = excludeArrayFlattenCols.split(";").map(_.trim).toList

    for(i <- 0 to fields.length-1){
      val field = fields(i)
      val fieldtype = field.dataType
      val fieldName = field.name
      fieldtype match {
        case arrayType: ArrayType =>
          println("ArrayType")
          if(! dontFlattenList.contains(fieldName)) {
            val fieldNamesExcludingArray = fieldNames.filter(_ != fieldName)
            val fieldNamesAndExplode = fieldNamesExcludingArray ++ Array(s"explode_outer($fieldName) as $fieldName")
            println("array => " + fieldNamesAndExplode)//.mkString("Array(", ", ", ")"))
            val explodedDf = df.selectExpr(fieldNamesAndExplode: _*)
            return flattenDataframe(explodedDf,keepParentFieldName, excludeArrayFlattenCols)
          }
        case structType: StructType =>
          println("StructType")
          val childFieldnames = structType.fieldNames.map(childname => fieldName +"."+childname)
          val newfieldNames = fieldNames.filter(_!= fieldName) ++ childFieldnames
          val renamedcols = newfieldNames.map(
            x => (col(x.toString)).as(x.toString.replace(".", "_")))
          println("struct => "+renamedcols)//.mkString("Array(", ", ", ")"))
          val explodedf = df.select(renamedcols:_*)
          return flattenDataframe(explodedf,keepParentFieldName, excludeArrayFlattenCols)
        case _ =>
      }
    }
    var cols:Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = null

    if(keepParentFieldName){
      cols = fieldNames.map(c => col(c.toString).as(c.toString))
    }
    else{
      cols = fieldNames.map(c => col(c.toString).as(c.toString.substring(c.toString.indexOf("_")+1)))
    }
    df.select(cols:_*)
  }
```

I get an error saying that the column odata doesn't exist. It's not reading the full fieldname with the ".". I'm wondering if at some step, I need to add a replace(".","") to the column name, but I'm not sure at which point to do this.

`AnalysisException: No such struct field odata in CheckInComment, CheckOutType, ContentTag, CustomizedPageStatus, ETag, Exists, IrmEnabled, Length, Level, LinkingUri, LinkingUrl, MajorVersion, MinorVersion, Name, ServerRelativeUrl, TimeCreated, TimeLastModified, Title, UIVersion, UIVersionLabel, UniqueId, odata.editLink, odata.id, odata.type`

Comment: Given the poor quality of the inherited code (`return`, `var`, not tail-recursive, etc.) I'd be inclined to re-write the whole function from scratch.

Comment: @Tim, I also used the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863489/flatten-nested-json-in-scala-spark-dataframe, and I still got the same error