# spark complaining column not found even though error message show its there

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to flatten a nested json to individual columns and apply transformation. In the real scenario its a nested json so I can't predict what columns are nested ahead of time, so I am using recursive looping to traverse through the json and flatten it out. Below is the sample scenario:

##### Input JSON

```
{
    "order": {      
        "name": "John Doe",
        "address": {
            "state": "NY"
        },
        "orders": [
            {
                "order_id": 1001,
                "quarter": "2023-06-30"
            },
            {
                "order_id": 1002,
                "quarter": "2023-06-29"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

After flattening, it displays as below:

```
+-------------------+----------+---------------------+------------------------+
|order.address.state|order.name|order.orders.order_id|order.orders.quarter    |
+-------------------+----------+---------------------+------------------------+
|NY                 |John Doe  |[1001, 1002]         |[2023-06-30, 2023-06-29]|
|NY                 |John Doe  |[1001, 1002]         |[2023-06-30, 2023-06-29]|
+-------------------+----------+---------------------+------------------------+
```

But when i try to transform the column it complains that `order.address.state` is missing, even though the error message lists this specific column as one of the columns !!!!

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
> Column 'order.address.state' does not exist. Did you mean one of the
> following? [order.address.state, order.orders.quarter, order.name,
> order.orders.order_id];

##### Code Snippet

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1;
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonFlattener {

    // UDF to transform values based on the config file
    private static UserDefinedFunction udfTransform = functions.udf(
        (UDF1<Object, Object>) value -> {
            // Your transformation logic based on the config file
            // Here, we're simply appending 'transformed_' prefix to the value
            return "transformed_" + value;
        }, DataTypes.StringType);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .appName("JsonFlattener")
            .master("local")
            .getOrCreate();

        spark.udf().register("getQuarterOfYearUDF", getQuarterOfYearUDF, DataTypes.IntegerType);

        // Read the JSON file
        Dataset<Row> input = spark.read().option("multiLine","true").option("inferSchema","true").json("/home/akannan/INPUT/orders2.json");

        input.show(false);

        // Flatten the nested JSON recursively based on the level of nesting
        Dataset<Row> flattened = flattenNestedJson(input);
        flattened.printSchema();
        flattened.show(false);

        // Read the config file to determine which columns need transformation
        String configPath = "/home/akannan/INPUT/orders_modify.json"; // Specify the path to your config file
        String configFileContents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(configPath)));
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<UDFFullReplace.FieldTransformation>>() {
        }.getType();
        List<UDFFullReplace.FieldTransformation> transformations = gson.fromJson(configFileContents, listType);

        // Apply the UDF transformation to the specified columns
        Dataset<Row> transformed = applyTransformation(flattened, transformations);

        transformed.show(false);
        transformed.printSchema();
        // Unflatten the DataFrame back to the original JSON format
        Dataset<Row> unflattened = unflattenJson(transformed);

        // Show the result
        unflattened.show();
    }

    private static Dataset<Row> flattenNestedJson(Dataset<Row> input) {
        StructType schema = input.schema();
        return flattenNestedJson(input, "", schema);
    }

    private static Dataset<Row> flattenNestedJson(Dataset<Row> input, String prefix, DataType dataType) {
        if (dataType instanceof StructType) {
            StructType structType = (StructType) dataType;
            for (StructField field : structType.fields()) {
                String columnName = field.name();
                String fullColumnName = prefix.isEmpty() ? columnName : prefix + "." + columnName;
                DataType columnDataType = field.dataType();
                input = flattenColumn(input, fullColumnName, columnDataType);
            }
            input = input.drop(prefix);
        } else if (dataType instanceof ArrayType) {
            ArrayType arrayType = (ArrayType) dataType;
            DataType elementType = arrayType.elementType();
//            input = input.withColumn(prefix, functions.explode(functions.col(prefix)))
//                .selectExpr("*", prefix + ".*")
//                .drop(prefix);
            input = input.withColumn(prefix, functions.explode_outer(functions.col(prefix)));

            input = flattenColumn(input, prefix, elementType);
        }
        return input;
    }

    private static Dataset<Row> flattenColumn(Dataset<Row> input, String columnName, DataType columnDataType) {
        if (columnDataType instanceof StructType) {
            input = flattenNestedJson(input, columnName, columnDataType);
        } else if (columnDataType instanceof  ArrayType) {
            input = flattenNestedJson(input, columnName, columnDataType);
        }
        else {
            input = input.withColumn(columnName, functions.col(columnName));
        }
        return input;
    }

    private static Dataset<Row> applyTransformation(Dataset<Row> input, List<UDFFullReplace.FieldTransformation> transformations) {
        input.cache();
        for (UDFFullReplace.FieldTransformation transformation : transformations) {
            String[] fieldNames = transformation.getName().split("\\.");
            String columnName = transformation.getName();
            String udf = transformation.getUdf();

//            input = input.withColumn(columnName, udfTransform.apply(functions.col(columnName)));
            input =  input.withColumn(columnName, functions.concat(functions.col(columnName), functions.lit("_suffix")));
        }
        return input;


    }

    private static Dataset<Row> unflattenJson(Dataset<Row> input) {
        // Group the columns based on the nested structure and create a struct
        StructType schema = input.schema();
        StructField[] fields = schema.fields();
        Column[] columns = new Column[fields.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            columns[i] = functions.col(fields[i].name());
        }

        // Create a single column named 'value' with the struct
        //Dataset<Row> withStructColumn = input.withColumn("value", functions.struct(columns));
        Dataset<Row> withStructColumn = input.withColumn("value", functions.struct(
            input.col("order.address.state").alias("state"),
            input.col("order.name").alias("name"),
            input.col("order.orders.order_id").alias("order_id"),
            input.col("order.orders.quarter").alias("quarter")
        ));

        // Convert the DataFrame to a JSON string
        Dataset<Row> jsonString = withStructColumn.select(functions.to_json(functions.col("value")).alias("json"));

        // Parse the JSON string and extract the struct column
        return jsonString.select(functions.from_json(functions.col("json"), schema).alias("value")).select("value.*");
    }


    static UDF1<String, Integer> getQuarterOfYearUDF = (dateString) -> {
        String[] parts = dateString.split("-");
        int month = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        int quarter = (month - 1) / 3 + 1;
        return quarter;
    };
}
```

##### Stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Column 'order.address.state' does not exist. Did you mean one of the following? [order.address.state, order.orders.quarter, order.name, order.orders.order_id];
'Project [concat('order.address.state, _suffix) AS order.address.state#95, order.name#15, order.orders.order_id#27, order.orders.quarter#34]
+- Project [order.address.state#9, order.name#15, order.orders.order_id#27, order.orders.quarter#34]
   +- Project [order#0, order.address.state#9, order.name#15, order.orders.order_id#27, order.orders.quarter#34]
      +- Project [order#0, order.address.state#9, order.name#15, order.orders#22, order.orders.order_id#27, order#0.orders.quarter AS order.orders.quarter#34]
         +- Project [order#0, order.address.state#9, order.name#15, order.orders#22, order#0.orders.order_id AS order.orders.order_id#27]
            +- Project [order#0, order.address.state#9, order.name#15, order.orders#22]
               +- Generate explode(order#0.orders), true, [order.orders#22]
                  +- Project [order#0, order.address.state#9, order#0.name AS order.name#15]
                     +- Project [order#0, order#0.address.state AS order.address.state#9]
                        +- Relation [order#0] json

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$7(CheckAnalysis.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$7$adapted(CheckAnalysis.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1(TreeNode.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1$adapted(TreeNode.scala:366)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1(TreeNode.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1$adapted(TreeNode.scala:366)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$6(CheckAnalysis.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$6$adapted(CheckAnalysis.scala:192)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:533)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1(CheckAnalysis.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$adapted(CheckAnalysis.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis$(CheckAnalysis.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$2(QueryExecution.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:510)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$1(Dataset.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withPlan(Dataset.scala:3887)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.select(Dataset.scala:1519)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withColumns(Dataset.scala:2542)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withColumn(Dataset.scala:2480)
    at org.nypd.nextgen.data.pipeline.JsonFlattener.applyTransformation(JsonFlattener.java:116)
    at org.nypd.nextgen.data.pipeline.JsonFlattener.main(JsonFlattener.java:57)
```

Comment: can you plz post the printSchema of your df After flattening

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not complete but what I forsee here is a problem with the dots inside the column names.

Try to avoid that as dots are usually used to get nested fields. In general don't use any special character, only underscores.

If you really want to keep the dots, then when accessing the specified column, use back ticks (**`**)

```
flattened.withColumn("test", functions.col("`order.address.state`"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you have written very big logic to flatten array columns. You can use `inline` function to flatten array columns in line like below.

Use `.` to access any columns from struct & array.

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- order: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- orders: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- order_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- quarter: string (nullable = true)


scala> df.select("order.*").selectExpr("*", "inline(orders)").drop("orders").printSchema
root
 |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- order_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- quarter: string (nullable = true)


scala> df.select("order.*").selectExpr("*", "inline(orders)").drop("orders").show(false)
+-------+--------+--------+----------+
|address|name    |order_id|quarter   |
+-------+--------+--------+----------+
|{NY}   |John Doe|1001    |2023-06-30|
|{NY}   |John Doe|1002    |2023-06-29|
+-------+--------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: thanks @srinivas  in my real scenario i have a nested json schema so i have to do a recursive call to flatten it out. I guess in that case manually traversing through each json array and recursively flattening is the only option

Comment: You can check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863489/flatten-nested-json-in-scala-spark-dataframe/61863579#61863579

Comment: Thanks  @Srinivas . For the deflatten part how does this logic group all rows belonging to same id  comes under the same top element