# How to Flatten JSON file using pyspark

Tags: python, json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to flatten JSON file so that I can get output in table format.Ihavetried but not getting the output that I want

This is my JSON file :-

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "last_name": "B",
            "special_values": [
                {
                    "name": "address",
                    "value": "some adress"
                },
                {
                    "name": "city",
                    "value": "Chd"
                },
                {
                    "name": "zip_code",
                    "value": "160036"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "X",
            "last_name": "Y",
            "special_values": [
                {
                    "name": "adress",
                    "value": "some adress"
                },
                {
                    "name": "city",
                    "value": "Dallas"
                },
                {
                    "name": "zip_code",
                    "value": "02431"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want this output:-

```
|name|last_name|address|city  |zip_code|FIELD7|
|----|---------|-------|------|--------|------|
|A   |B        |some   |adress|chd     |160036|
|X   |Y        |some   |adress|Dallas  |02431 |
```

I have tried this code but getting different output :-

```
df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json(r"C:\Users\Lajo\Downloads\spark_ex2_input.json")
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode_outer,col


def flatten(df):
   # compute Complex Fields (Lists and Structs) in Schema   
   complex_fields = dict([(field.name, field.dataType)
                             for field in df.schema.fields
                             if type(field.dataType) == ArrayType or  type(field.dataType) == StructType])
   while len(complex_fields)!=0:
      col_name=list(complex_fields.keys())[0]
      print ("Processing :"+col_name+" Type : "+str(type(complex_fields[col_name])))
    
      # if StructType then convert all sub element to columns.
      # i.e. flatten structs
      if (type(complex_fields[col_name]) == StructType):
         expanded = [col(col_name+'.'+k).alias(col_name+'_'+k) for k in [ n.name for n in  complex_fields[col_name]]]
         df=df.select("*", *expanded).drop(col_name)
    
      # if ArrayType then add the Array Elements as Rows using the explode function
      # i.e. explode Arrays
      elif (type(complex_fields[col_name]) == ArrayType):    
         df=df.withColumn(col_name,explode_outer(col_name))
    
      # recompute remaining Complex Fields in Schema       
      complex_fields = dict([(field.name, field.dataType)
                             for field in df.schema.fields
                             if type(field.dataType) == ArrayType or  type(field.dataType) == StructType])
   return df

df_flatten = flatten(df)
df_flatten.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to flatten the data *before* making it into a data frame. Consider reading the JSON file with the built-in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/json.html) library. Then you can perform the following operation on the resulting `data` object.

```py
data = data["records"] # It seems that the data you want is in "records"
for entry in data:
    for special_value in entry["special_values"]: # Add each special value to the entry
        entry[special_value["name"]] = special_value["value"]
    del entry["special_values"] # Remove the "special_values" list
```

See below for an example using list and dict comprehension (about 10% slower than the above). The `x | y` syntax is for [merging the dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38987/21891079) created with dict comprehension. You can use it in Python versions > 3.9.0.

```py
data = [
    (
        {k: v for k, v in entry.items() if k != "special_values"} |
        {
            value["name"]: value["value"]
            for value in entry["special_values"]
        }
    )
    for entry in data["records"]
]
```

Here it is on one line:

```py
data = [({k: v for k, v in entry.items() if k != "special_values"} | {value["name"]: value["value"] for value in entry["special_values"]}) for entry in data["records"]]
```

Here is the before and after.

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "last_name": "B",
            "special_values": [
                {
                    "name": "address",
                    "value": "some adress"
                },
                {
                    "name": "city",
                    "value": "Chd"
                },
                {
                    "name": "zip_code",
                    "value": "160036"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "X",
            "last_name": "Y",
            "special_values": [
                {
                    "name": "adress",
                    "value": "some adress"
                },
                {
                    "name": "city",
                    "value": "Dallas"
                },
                {
                    "name": "zip_code",
                    "value": "02431"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```
[{'address': 'some adress',
  'city': 'Chd',
  'last_name': 'B',
  'name': 'A',
  'zip_code': '160036'},
 {'adress': 'some adress',
  'city': 'Dallas',
  'last_name': 'Y',
  'name': 'X',
  'zip_code': '02431'}]
```

You can, then, create a data frame from the `data` object.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show()
```

```
+-----------+------+---------+----+--------+-----------+
|    address|  city|last_name|name|zip_code|     adress|
+-----------+------+---------+----+--------+-----------+
|some adress|   Chd|        B|   A|  160036|       NULL|
|       NULL|Dallas|        Y|   X|   02431|some adress|
+-----------+------+---------+----+--------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Please find the simple spark sql solution below ( tried different way ).

```
scala> spark.table("input").toJSON.show(false)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"records":[{"last_name":"B","name":"A","special_values":[{"name":"address","value":"some adress"},{"name":"city","value":"Chd"},{"name":"zip_code","value":"160036"}]},{"last_name":"Y","name":"X","special_values":[{"name":"adress","value":"some adress"},{"name":"city","value":"Dallas"},{"name":"zip_code","value":"02431"}]}]}|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

spark.sql("""
    WITH record AS (
        SELECT
            inline_outer(records)
        FROM input
    ),
    flatten AS (
        SELECT
            r.name,
            r.last_name,
            aggregate(
                    r.special_values, '',
                    (acc, elem) -> concat_ws(' ', acc,elem.value, ','),
                    acc -> from_csv(ltrim(acc), 'address string, city string, zip_code string')) as special_values
        FROM record r
    )
    SELECT
        name,
        last_name,
        special_values.*
    FROM flatten
 """).show(false)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+----+---------+------------+--------+--------+
|name|last_name|address     |city    |zip_code|
+----+---------+------------+--------+--------+
|A   |B        |some adress | Chd    | 160036 |
|X   |Y        |some adress | Dallas | 02431  |
+----+---------+------------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Priya, I have written logic to flatten all columns in scala & You can check this  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863489/flatten-nested-json-in-scala-spark-dataframe/61863579#61863579

Comment: My requirement is only PySpark

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion it is much easier with the library '[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)' and less code is needed.

```
df = pd.read_json("your_json_file.json")
records = df["records"]
flattened_data = []
for record in records:
    row = {
        "name": record["name"],
        "last_name": record["last_name"]
    }

    for special_value in record["special_values"]:
        row[special_value["name"]] = special_value["value"]
    flattened_data.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(flattened_data)
print(df.to_csv(sep="|", index=False))
```

the result looks like this

```
name|last_name|address|city|zip_code|adress
A|B|some adress|Chd|160036|
X|Y||Dallas|02431|some adress
```

Comment: But the requirement is to code only in Pyspark

Comment: @Priya Please add this requirement to the original question so that others trying to answer your question will be aware of it. To clarify, is `pyspark` the only external package you are allowed to use?

Comment: Sorry by mistake I forgot to write PySpark