# Expand struct fields and compare the field in 2 datasets

Tags: arrays, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, struct

[image]

need some suggestions here. I have 2 datasets with fields of type array and struct and I'm trying to find difference at field level between these 2 datasets. The topLevelReport generates difference for top level fields (example: name)  and if there is a diff (>0) then lowLevelReport expands those nested columns based on the data type (logic in curateColumns method) and calculate diff. The code is working fine for array but not for struct . For example, I have this struct column "name", it does generate the value for “name” column but when it shows diff with the name column in other dataset, it does not expand and generate values for brand and keywords.

My understanding is that explodeStruct method is not mapping brand and keywords as name.brand and name.keywords and therefore when lowlevelreport tries to filter fields that contain ".", it can't find these fields???

```
> name: struct (nullable = true)  
|  |-- brand: string (nullable = true)
 |  |-- keywords: string (nullable = true)
> 
> 
> 
> override def validate(df1: DataFrame,
>                       df2: DataFrame): Dataset[DiffReportModel] = {
> 
>     val columns = curateColumns(df1)
>     val topLevelReport: Seq[DiffReportModel] = columns.
>         filter(!_.toString.contains(".")).
>         map(column => calculateColumnPercentageGap(df1, df2, df1.count, column))
>     
>     val lowLevelReportFieldNames = topLevelReport.filter(_.anyMistmatch()).map(_.attribute)
>    
>     val lowLevelReport: Seq[DiffReportModel] = columns.filter(_.toString.contains(".")).
>         filter(column => selectNestedColumn(lowLevelReportFieldNames, column)).
>         map(column => calculateColumnPercentageGap(df1, df2, df1.count, column))
> 
>     (topLevelReport ++ lowLevelReport).toDS() }
> 
> def explodeArray(df: DataFrame, c: StructField): Seq[Column] = {
>     Try(
>         df.select(explode(col(c.name)) as "parent")
>             .schema.filter(c => c.name == "parent")
>             .flatMap(_.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType].fields)
>             .map(f => sort_array(col(c.name)).getField(f.name).as(s"${c.name}.${f.name}"))
>     ).getOrElse(Seq()) }
> 
> def selectNestedColumn(lowLevelReportFieldNames: Seq[String], column:
> Column) = {
>     lowLevelReportFieldNames.contains(
>         column.toString.split(',').head.split('(').last) }
> 
> def explodeStruct(st: StructType, c: StructField): Seq[Column] = {
>     Seq(col(c.name)) ++ st.fields.map(f => col(s"${c.name}.${f.name}")) }
> 
> 
> def sortAndExplodeArray(df: DataFrame, c: StructField): Seq[Column] >
> {
>     Seq(sort_array(col(c.name)).as(c.name)) ++ explodeArray(df, c) >}

/**
 * Return a list of [[Column]]
 * @param schema
 * @return
 */

> def curateColumns(df: DataFrame): Seq[Column] = {
>     df.schema.flatMap(c => c.dataType match {
>         case st: StructType => explodeStruct(st, c)
>         case _: ArrayType => sortAndExplodeArray(df, c)         case _ => Seq(col(c.name))
>     }) }
```

Comment: @rkochar - Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you please add some input & expected output ?

Comment: for flattening columns in dataset, you can check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863489/flatten-nested-json-in-scala-spark-dataframe/61863579#61863579

Comment: please add some sample input & your expected output

Comment: @Srinivas  I have 2 datasets with same columns. The datatypes of those columns are struct and array.

Comment: For example:     Struct type, not working as expected
pcs: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- brand: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- keywords: string (nullable = true)

Comment: Array type —works fine
|-- abc: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- abc1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- abc2: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- abc3: integer (nullable = true)

Comment: the objective of explode array explodeStruct method is to convert fields into -->  name, name.brand, name.keyword, abc, abc.abc1, abc.abc2 etc.  Calculate difference between these fields in dataset 1 and dataset 2. lowLevelReport  generate values for top fields such as name and abc. If these fields has any difference in values, it then generate diff for nested fields and publish this into a csv

Comment: @Srinivas Attached image of the expected output